# Web Storm identifier expected error when I use brace to pass vue function parameters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webstorm

This is my code

[image: Screen Shot]

Here is the error ,how to handle this error?
Should I disable this inspection for webstorm,
or change the code style?

I have already install the vue plugin.
as also set the ES6 Language Version.

The framework I am using is wepy , which I link to .wpy file 
to vue template.

Comment: it doesn't look like a valid Vue.js syntax - passing interpolation as function argument is not expected. Must be smth specific to framework you are using

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `VueJS` plugin (Settings/Preferences | Plugins)

-- it will set up own file types and other stuff (files will have own icon etc)

Also check your JavaScript Syntex version set to ES6 ([Details](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/ecmascript-6-in-webstorm-transpiling/))

Comment: thanks for your help, here are some additional info about this error.
I have already install the vue plugin. also set the ES6 Language Version.
The framework I am using is wepy , which I link to .wpy file to vue template.

Comment: what happens when you pass the argument like this : onProductClick(item) ?

Comment: it make the item as string "item" but not object.